# pyside connection Error "RuntimeError: Failed to connect signal clicked()"

Tags: python, pyside, qt-designer

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

import sys
import stackwid

class Dialog(QDialog,stackwid.Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(Dialog,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


        self.camButton.clicked.connect(self.set())


    def set(self):

        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Dialog()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

I wanted to connect clicked() signal emitted by camButton(PushButton) to slot which is a function set().This just does not run .

```
RuntimeError: Failed to connect signal clicked()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't connect the signal to your `set()`-function, but to it's return value. You just need to remove the parenthesis, then it should work:

```
self.camButton.clicked.connect(self.set)
```

Comment: Thanx that worked...

But I need to pass extra argument, the no to set into set method.

    def set(self,no):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(no)

how to go about this?
Should not i use,
    self.camButton.clicked.connect(self.set(no))

Comment: The [`clicked`-Signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) of a button is emitted with only one boolean argument, `checked`. If you want to pass another parameter to your slot (of function in this case), you need to define your own signal and emit that when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 5):

Passing extra arguments to slots, this may help you ,good luck!

```
self.camButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set(index))

def set(self, index):

    self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
```