# PySide Failed to connect signal clicked()

Tags: python, pyside

I have an application which should open a web browser address after button click. Main function look like this:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super( MainWindow, self ).__init__( parent = parent )
        self.button_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.webButton = PicButton(QtGui.QPixmap("images/button.png"))
        self.filmButton.clicked.connect(openWebpage("http://some.web.adress"))
        self.button_layout.addWidget(self.webButton)
```

And function for opening a web browser looks this way:

```
def openWebpage(address):
    try:
        import webbrowser

        webbrowser.open(address)

    except ImportError as exc:
        sys.stderr.write("Error: failed to import settings module ({})".format(exc))
```

After running this code, no application window visible, web browser fires immediately, and console returns:

```
Failed to connect signal clicked().
```

Simple functions connected to this button works properly (for instance - printing text to console). Any ideas?

Comment: Is `self.filmButton.clicked.connect(openWebpage("http://some.web.adress"))` correct? I mean exactly the `openWebpage("http://some.web.adress")`-part. I've thought it is only permitted to use it as `self.filmButton.clicked.connect(openWebpage)`. Also, provide a type of "filmButton".

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894866/pyside-connection-error-runtimeerror-failed-to-connect-signal-clicked#comment19156148_13894993), @VictorPolevoy is right.

Answer (score 0):

To pass an argument in the slot you need to construct a lambda expression:

```
self.filmButton.clicked.connect(lambda: openWebpage("http://some.web.adress"))
```

To explain this a little more, the connect() method accepts a callable object as its argument. The lambda expression, which is basically an anonymous function, is one such callable object. You could also wrap your function call in the `functools` module's `partial()` method to achieve the same thing. For more about what constitutes a Python callable, see [What is a "callable" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

As people said a bit earlier - use lambda, or use a normal `slot` which gives (to me at least) more readability.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.filmButton.clicked.connect(self._film_button_clicked)

@pyqtSlot() # note that this is not really necessary
def _film_button_clicked(self):
    self.openWebpage('http://some.web.adress')
```